# Where is the mention of 'Shiva is Supreme Lord of Vishnu and Vishnu is Supreme Lord of Shiva'?

Tags: vishnu, mahabharata, shiva, scripture

There is a popular verse:

> **शिवाय विष्णुरूपाय शिवरूपाय विष्णवे । 
>
>   शिवस्य हृदयं विष्णुर्विष्णोश्च हृदयं शिवः ॥** 
>   *“Shivaya VishnuRoopaya , Shivarupaya Vishnave , Shivasya hirdayam VishnurVishnoscha hridayam Shivah “*
>
>   
>   Shiva is in the form of Vishnu, as Vishnu is in the form of Shiva . Shiva is in the heart of Vishnu as Vishnu is in the heart of Shiva.

[image: Hari-Hara]
However, Some people are always in debate regarding Supremacy of Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva. In the Puranas also Shaiva Puranas call Shiva as Lord of Vishnu and Vaishnava Puranas call Vishnu as Lord of Shiva.

**Is there some statement in scripture calling Vishnu as Lord of Shiva and Shiva as Lord of Vishnu ? If it is, where is it stated ?**

Comment: Haha, In the pic both looking chubby and cute.

Comment: from which "scripture" this verse is ? "“Shivaya VishnuRoopaya , Shivarupaya Vishnave , Shivasya hirdayam VishnurVishnoscha hridayam Shivah"?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Lord Shiva being Supreme Lord of Vishnu and Lord Vishnu being Supreme Lord of Shiva is stated in **Harivamsa Parva of Mahabharata in 2.125.41**

> रुद्रस्य परमो विष्णुर्विष्णोश्च परम: शिवः ।
>   एक एव द्विधा भूतो लोके चरति नित्यसः ॥
>   *rudrasya paramo viShNurviShNoshcha paramaH shivaH |
> eka eva dvidhA bhUto loke charati nityashaH ||2.125.41*
>   
>   **The supreme lord of Rudra (Shiva) is Vishnu and the supreme lord of Vishnu is Shiva. The same lord is moving in the world always in two forms.**

Also in Harivamsha Parva of Mahabharata in 2.125.29

> शिवाय विष्णुरूपाय विष्णवे शिवरूपिणे ।
>   यथान्तरं न पश्यमि तेन तौ दिशतः शिवम् ॥
>   *shivAya viShNurUpAya viShNave shivarUpiNe |
> yathAntaraM na pashyAmi tena tau dishataH shivam || 2.125.29*
>
> **Shiva is in the form of Vishnu and Vishnu is in the form of Shiva. There is no difference between them and both provide Auspiciousness.**

Comment: It's very annoying when Hindus fight(maybèe not literally but verbally) over the supremacy of their God. *Brahma Vishnu SadaShiv jaanat aviveka... Pranavaakshar mein shobhit, ye teeno eka* Your post is an amazing reply to those ignorant people, and it has a beautiful source too. Thanks, jai Maata di ^-^

Comment: @ABcDexter  Here in Shiva Purana it goes on like only a devotee of Shiva inherit the wealth of a Shiva devotee. does this look like intolerance?
 http://www.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/siva-mahapurana/vol-iii/chapter-148/topic-1

Comment: @Ajay Let me read and translate myself.

Comment: That last slokha also appears in skandOpanisad, which is attributed to Yajur Veda (but not found in any of the shakhas available today).

Answer (score 14):

Equality of Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu's equality are shown not one time but many times in Mahabharata
**Tezz reply is also very good! and I like that**

let's continue :—

> Vaisampayana continued,
>   "Phalguna then beheld him--
>   Mahadeva--that god of blazing
>   splendour-that wielder of the
>   Pinaka-that one who had his abode
>   on the mountains (of Kailasa)--
>   accompanied by Uma. Bending
>   down on his knee and bowing with
>   his head, that conqueror of hostile
>   cities-the son of Pritha worshipped
>   Hara and inclined him to grace.
>   And Arjuna said, 'O Kapardin, O
>   chief of all gods, O destroyer of the
>   eyes of Bhaga, O god of gods, O
>   Mahadeva, O thou of blue throat, O
>   thou of matted locks, I know thee
>   as the Cause of all causes. O thou
>   of three eyes, O lord of all! Thou
>   art the refuge of all the gods! This
>   universe hath sprung from thee.
>   Thou art incapable of being
>   vanquished by the three worlds of
>   the celestials, the Asuras, and
>   men. **Thou art Siva in the form of
>   Vishnu, and Vishnu in the form of
>   Siva.** Thou destroyedest of old the
>   great sacrifice of Daksha. O Hari, O
>   Rudra, I bow to thee. Thou hast an
>   eye on thy forehead. O Sarva, O
>   thou that rainest objects of desire,
>   O bearer of the trident, O wielder
>   of the Pinaka, O Surya, O thou of
>   pure body, O Creator of all, I bow
>   to thee.

—— **The Mahabharata, Book 3:
Vana Parva: Kairata Parva: Section
XXXIX**

> "Sanjaya said, 'Then Partha, with a
>   cheerful soul and joined hands and
>   eyes expanded (in wonder), gazed
>   at the god having the bull for his
>   mark and who was the receptacle
>   of every energy. **And he beheld the
>   offerings he made every night to
>   Vasudeva lying by the side of the
>   Three-eyed deity.** The son of
>   Pandu then, mentally worshiping
>   both Krishna and Sarva, said unto
>   the latter, 'I desire (to obtain) the
>   celestial weapon.' Hearing these
>   words of Partha desiring the boon
>   he sought, god Siva smilingly said
>   unto Vasudeva and Arjuna,
>   'Welcome to you, ye foremost of
>   men! I know the wish cherished by
>   you, and the business for which
>   you have come here. I will give you
>   what you wish.

—— **The Mahabharata, Book 7:
Drona Parva: Abhimanyu-badha
Parva: Section LXXXI**

You can see that there is clearly
written that Arjuna got all the
offerings in right side of Rudra that
he made to krishna every night.

> Vishnu and Agni and Soma became
>   (as already said) the arrow. **The
>   universe is said to consist of Agni
>   and Soma. The universe is similarly
>   said to consist of Vishnu. Vishnu
>   is, again, the Soul of the holy
>   Bhava of immeasurable energy.
>   For this the touch of that bow-
>   string became unbearable to the
>   Asuras.**

—— **The Mahabharata, Book 8:
Karna Parva: Section 34**

Here vishnu is rudra's soul.

> O son of Pandu, Rudra should be
>   known to have always Narayana for
>   his Soul. If that deity of deities,
>   viz., Maheswara, be worshipped,
>   then **O Partha, is the puissant
>   Narayana also worshiped. I am
>   the Soul, O son of Pandu, of all
>   the worlds, of all the universe.
>   Rudra, again, is my Soul. It is for
>   this that I always adore him.**

——**The Mahabharata, Book 12:
Santi Parva: Section CCCXLII**

Here Rudra is Vishnu's soul and
Vishnu is Rudra's soul.

but if you want it on a larger scale just go on my blog:—

**Equality of Lord Rudra and Lord Vishnu in
Mahabharata**
http://shivaandvishnu.blogspot.in/2017/09/equality-of-lord-rudra-and-lord-vishnu.html?m=1