# Has Siva spoken in favor of the varnashrama system?

Tags: shiva, caste-system, varna

What has Siva said about the caste or varna system?

Answer (score 10):

I will post some references where Lord Shiva spoke about Varnasrama Dharma.

In **[SECTION CXLIII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b108.htm), Anushasana Parva of Mahabharata**, Maheshwara says to Goddess Uma  that varna comes by birth is just for sake of classification and later conduct alone decides Varna and Varna can be changed.

> Neither birth, nor the purificatory rites, nor learning, nor
>   offspring, can be regarded as grounds for conferring upon one the
>   regenerate status. Verily, conduct is the only ground. All Brahmanas
>   in this world are Brahmanas in consequence of conduct. A Sudra, if he
>   is established on good conduct, is regarded as possessed of the status
>   of a Brahmana. The status of Brahma, O auspicious lady, is equal
>   wherever it exists. Even this is my opinion. He, indeed, is a Brahmana
>   in whom the status of Brahma exists,--that condition which is bereft
>   of attributes and which has no stain attached to it. The boon-giving
>   Brahma, while he created all creatures, himself said that the
>   distribution of human beings into the four orders dependent on birth
>   is only for purposes of classification.

Comment: I will post more after collecting some  references..

Comment: I was one second short of answering this lol.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury ok. I was searching for a Shiva Purana quote but missed it somehow. Will  update with it.

Comment: @SK Mahabharta is neutral text where Shiva is also praised. Some people claim even Ithihasas such as Ramayana and Mahabharata are Vaishnava scriptures. But If we read  properly we see it as neutral text. For example, see [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/13598). Cherry Picking verses may produce biased opinions which some people do.

Comment: I don't see Siva being in favor of caste since he was insulted by Daksha for being a "pakhandi" It was only after Daksha Yagya that the Brahminic order gave him his share of sacrifices. @the destroyer

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes like cherry picking abheda verses alone.

Comment: But  this sentence " A Sudra, if he is established on good conduct, is regarded as possessed of the status of a Brahmana"  is talking about a Shudra who is that by birth. :D Otherwise it does not make any sense. @TheDestroyer